# Nested For Loops and Storing Results in ?Vector?

Tags: r

I've written a nested for loop that does what I want. However, my data storage within the loop is not sufficient. I have tried implementing different temp vectors, but I know I'm just not wrapping my head around this well. These loops are going to generate 96 values... a full j loop (all 4 iterations) will produce the 12 values that will eventually be one matrix. Each i iteration, therefore, ultimately, creates one of the eight tables I need. Maybe a vector isn't the best (maybe I could get the loops to make my separate matrices? - to then throw into Kable). Clearly what I have right now (indexing into the vector with i isn't a solution. Thank you so much for your help!

```
subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators <- structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), indicator = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", 
"5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", 
"7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", 
"6", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", 
"8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", 
"8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
"6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", 
"4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
"8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "8", 
"8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", 
"7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
"6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", 
"4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", 
"8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", 
"6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", 
"8", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", 
"7", "7", "8", "8", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", 
"6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", 
"8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", "7", 
"7", "8", "8", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"), ObservationOrder = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 
4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), score = c(3.5, 3.5, 
2, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 
4, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 2, 1.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.66666666666667, 3, 1.33333333333333, 
2, 1, 1.5, 1.33333333333333, 2, 2, 2.5, 2.33333333333333, 2, 
1.33333333333333, 2.5, 2.33333333333333, 2.5, 1, 4, 3.5, 3, 1, 
2.5, 3, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 1.5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 1.5, 3, 1.33333333333333, 
2, 2.5, 2.66666666666667, 1.5, 2.5, 1.33333333333333, 3, 2, 1.66666666666667, 
2.5, 2.5, 2.66666666666667, 3, 3, 2.33333333333333, 2.5, 2, 1.66666666666667, 
3.5, 3, 1.66666666666667, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 4, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 3, 3, 1.5, 
3.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 3, 1, 3, 0.5, 1.5, 0, 2.5, 1, 2.5, 0.5, 
2, 3.5, 3, 0.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 
1, 3.5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3.5, 3, 3, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 
2.5, 2, 2, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2, 2, 2, 3.5, 2, 3, 3.5, 1.5, 
3, 1, 2.5, 1, 3, 1, 3.5, 2, 3, 2, 2.5, 1, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 3, 
2.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 1, 2.5, 1, 2, 0.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 
3.5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 0.5, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 
2, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 1.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3.5, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 
4, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3, 4, 
2.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 2, 3, 
2, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 3.5, 1.5, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 
2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 4, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 
3, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 4, 3.5, 
3, 3, 3.5, 3, 3, 2.5, 4, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 1.5, 
2, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 1, 
3, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3.5, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 3, 2.5, 
3.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3.5, 3, 
3.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3, 1, 
2.5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1.5, 1.66666666666667, 
3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 1, 2.5, 1.66666666666667, 
2.5, 1.5, 3, 2.66666666666667, 2.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 
2, 3, 1, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0.5, 
1, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 2, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 
1.5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 0.5, 2.5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 
0.5, 4, 0.5, 4, 1.5, 3, 0.5, 3, 0, 3, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 2, 
2, 4, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 
3, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
3, 3.5, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3.5, 1, 2, 
1.5, 3.5, 2, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 
3, 2.5, 0, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 1, 3.5, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2.5, 
1.5, 3, 2, 2, 3.5, 2.5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1.5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 
1.5, 1, 0, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
3.5, 3, 1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 
2, 2.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2.5, 2, 0.5, 
1, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 2, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 
2, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 3, 1, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 
1, 0, 1, 1.5, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 
3, 2, 0, 1, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -840L))
```

```
hg10.1<-vector('list',32)
hg10.2<-vector('list',32)
hg10.3<-vector('list',32)

for (i in 1:8){
  for (j in 1:4){
      TLColTemp<-cohen.d((subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators[subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$Group==1 &
                                                                 subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$indicator==i &
                                                                 subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$ObservationOrder==j,]$score),
                         (subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators[subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$Group==2 &
                                                                 subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$indicator==i &
                                                                 subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$ObservationOrder==j,]$score),
                         pooled=T,hedges.correction = T,na.rm=T)
      hg10.1[[i]]<-TLColTemp$estimate

      ColCompTemp<-cohen.d((subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators[subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$Group==2 &
                                                                   subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$indicator==i &
                                                                   subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$ObservationOrder==j,]$score),
                           (subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators[subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$Group==3 &
                                                                   subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$indicator==i &
                                                                   subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$ObservationOrder==j,]$score),
                           pooled=T,hedges.correction = T,na.rm=T)
      hg10.2[[i]]<-ColCompTemp$estimate

      TLCompTemp<-cohen.d((subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators[subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$Group==1 &
                                                                  subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$indicator==i &
                                                                  subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$ObservationOrder==j,]$score),
                          (subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators[subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$Group==3 &
                                                                  subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$indicator==i &
                                                                  subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators$ObservationOrder==j,]$score),
                          pooled=T,hedges.correction = T,na.rm=T)
      hg10.3[[i]]<-TLCompTemp$estimate
  }
}
```

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around what is actually needed to boil this monster down a little  am I missing something here or is the assignment into `hg10.x[[i]]` a typo? Right now it only keeps the results of j==4 and fills values only for indices 1:8.. I guess it should be `(i-1)*4+j` instead?

Comment: I knew  that `hg10.x[[i]]' didn't work :) So, I wrote it, but I know it's wrong. Thank you for your help! Yes. (i-1)*4+j seems to fix it :) My math brain died a little thinking about that.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to fill the eight separate matrices? If not, I can make it work from here.

Comment: I hope you can go with one of the suggested `dplyr` ways (I think Dave has found a slightly more graceful way than I did) instead  those for-loops are just the devil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` way of getting all of the relevant estimates, if I understand the goal.  `est_1_2` is the d between group 1 and group 2, etc...

```
res <- subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators %>% 
   group_by(indicator, ObservationOrder) %>% 
   summarise(est_1_2 = cohen.d(score[which(Group == 1)], score[which(Group == 2)], pooled=T,hedges.correction = T,na.rm=T)$estimate, 
             est_2_3 = cohen.d(score[which(Group == 2)], score[which(Group == 3)], pooled=T,hedges.correction = T,na.rm=T)$estimate, 
             est_1_3 = cohen.d(score[which(Group == 1)], score[which(Group == 3)], pooled=T,hedges.correction = T,na.rm=T)$estimate) %>% 
   split(., .$indicator)
> res
$`1`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1                        1 -0.347    0.416   0.191
2 1                        2  0.798   -1.58   -0.532
3 1                        3 -0.0298   0.309   0.307
4 1                        4 -0.0940   0.309   0.188

$`2`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2                        1  0.597   0.156   0.819 
2 2                        2  0.0666 -0.0408  0.0256
3 2                        3 -0.413   0.0478 -0.251 
4 2                        4  0.178   0.246   0.510 

$`3`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 3                        1  -0.412   0.550  0.118 
2 3                        2   0.361  -0.263  0.0294
3 3                        3   0.353   0.769  1.09  
4 3                        4   0.305  -0.102  0.189 

$`4`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 4                        1 -0.288    0.153  -0.126
2 4                        2  0.919   -1.05   -0.340
3 4                        3 -0.0631   0.341   0.348
4 4                        4 -0.0559   0.766   0.689

$`5`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 5                        1  -0.524   0.773   0.572
2 5                        2   1.18   -0.715   0.293
3 5                        3   0.134   0.460   0.670
4 5                        4  -0.361   1.08    0.744

$`6`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 6                        1 -0.147    0.549   0.460
2 6                        2  0.993   -1.64   -0.196
3 6                        3 -0.0934   0.489   0.473
4 6                        4 -0.543    1.04    0.248

$`7`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 7                        1  -0.273   0.763  0.740 
2 7                        2   0.799  -0.932 -0.0997
3 7                        3  -0.643   0.870  0.506 
4 7                        4  -0.147   0.845  0.790 

$`8`
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   indicator [1]
  indicator ObservationOrder est_1_2 est_2_3 est_1_3
  <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 8                        1   0.266  0.106   0.419 
2 8                        2   0.830 -0.824   0.0903
3 8                        3   0.626  0.0371  0.409 
4 8                        4  -0.220  0.863   0.647
```

Comment: Apologies, I had pasted output rather than input in R.  I edited the answer now.

Comment: This helped me so much. I know tidyverse, but not this well. I can now apply this to computations. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach of first preparing a dataframe containing the parametrization for your later calculations and then using `purrr::pmap` to feed those params into a function that calculates your cohen.d estimator for each row:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(effsize)

param_df <- subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators %>%
  distinct(ind = indicator, obs_order = ObservationOrder) %>%
  arrange(ind, obs_order) %>%
  inner_join(
    tibble(group_a = c(1,2,1), group_b = c(2,3,3)),
    by = character()
  )

result <- param_df %>%
  mutate(
    cohen = pmap(
      .,
      .f = function(ind, obs_order, group_a, group_b) {
        tmp_d <- subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators %>%
          filter(
            indicator == ind,
            ObservationOrder== obs_order,
            Group == group_a
          ) %>%
          pull(score)

        tmp_f <- subgroup_years_aggregated_indicators %>%
          filter(
            indicator == ind,
            ObservationOrder== obs_order,
            Group == group_b
          ) %>%
          pull(score)
      
        tmp_cohen <- cohen.d(tmp_d, tmp_f, pooled = T, hedges.correction = T, na.rm = T)
      
        return(tmp_cohen$estimate)
      }
    )
  )
```